# Pass function via Custom Control Properties or custom events for Custom Controls?

Tags: xpages

Here is what I want to do.   I have a Custom Control with a button.  If I drop it on a page, I want the end user programmer to define what happens when the button is pushed.

I had three ideas on how to accomplish this but don't know if they are possible of of course would not know how to do it.

1. Pass a function through a custom property.  The button would call that custom property as a function. Is this possible?   If so how would I do it?   I tried it but it did not seem to work.

   compositeData.ssjs_clickOK("Hello World");
2. Define a custom event for the custom control.   Is this possible?  How would it be done.
3. Have the button call a unique function name that would need to be defined by the user programmer.  Seems a little messy but it might work.  How can my button code see if the function has been defined?   Would if (MySpecialFunction != null) work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using the following in one of my applications to pass a function to a custom control:

*1) In the custom control, add a property that will hold the function to be executed in our action button.  I'll call mine 'querySave'.  The property type must be 'javax.faces.el.MethodBinding'.  The editor must be 'Method Binding Editor'.*

*2). Here is the code behind the action button in the custom control for this example:*

```
if (compositeData.querySave) if (!compositeData.querySave.call()) return;
currentDocument.save();
```

*This says: If there is a function defined in the property 'querySave', call it.  If the function returns false, don't save the document.*

*3) Define a SSJS function that does what you need the action button to do.  I normally place mine in a SSJS library.  Make sure that the XPage has access to the function.*

*4) In the XPage that contains this control, use the editor for the property we created in step 1 (querySave in this example) and enter the name of the function that you created in step 3.  IMPORTANT: Do not add the parenthesis or parameters when you enter the function name - if you do, the function will be executed at load time rather than when you click the action button.  Also, don't add any code directly to the editor, just the function name. Any code in this editor will also execute at load time.*

Thanks to [Bill Hanson for the answer on Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/Lotus_SmartSuite/Lotus_Notes/Q_27323733.html#a36586440).

--

**Update:**

Here's a concrete example of such a custom control with a custom property where the SSJS function in question is called validateDocument:

```
<xc:component_buttons>
    <xc:this.validateFunctionName><![CDATA[#{javascript:validateDocument}]]></xc:this.validateFunctionName>
</xc:component_buttons>
```

And here is an example of the button in the custom control that calls the function:

```
<xp:button id="submit" value="Save">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:this.condition><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                if (compositeData.validateFunctionName) {
                    compositeData.validateFunctionName.call();
                }}]]>
                </xp:this.condition>
                <xp:save></xp:save>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: This is working.  Sort of.  I think I might be confused by your last step.  What I did was to create a function and place it in a SSJS library, I included the library as a resource on the xpage. I then just placed the name of the function in my CC property but I get the following error Script interpreter error, line=4, col=36: Java method 'setValue(undefined)' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText' not found.  setValue is the name of my function. I placed setValue in the editor and nothing more.

Comment: If I don't pass a parameter, this works great.  But I want my button to be able to pass a value to the function.  Sort of like a callback I guess.

Comment: Bruce, I have updated my answer with concrete examples. Hope it helps

Comment: Good question, Bruce. I don't know as I have not tried it. You could pass parameters as other custom properties. The question is then how to pass the parameters to the function when using .call() to call the function.

Comment: I used part of Sven's solution below to pass arguments.   I pass the arguments via an array.  But I think your idea will work too, which I might use.   Seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this question: [Pass javascript code to Custom Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292363/pass-javascript-code-to-custom-control)

My answer describes how to pass SSJS code from a custom control via a method binding.

**EDIT:**

1. Create a custom control *"ccSSJS"*
2. Add a property *ssjsCode* to your CC

   - Type: *javax.faces.el.MethodBinding*
   - Editor: Method Binding Editor
3. This is the source of the CC

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

      <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
           refreshMode="complete">
           <xp:this.action>
              <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                 var args = new Array();
                 args["abc"] = "123";
                 args["cde"] = "456";
                 compositeData.ssjsCode.invoke( facesContext, null );
              }]]>
           </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:button>
   </xp:view>
   ```
4. Create a XPage and add the Custom Control

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

   <xc:ccSSJS>
         <xc:this.ssjsCode>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
               var app = facesContext.getApplication();
               app.createMethodBinding("#{javascript:print( args['abc'] )}", null); 
            }]]>
         </xc:this.ssjsCode>
      </xc:ccSSJS>

   </xp:view>
   ```

If you click the button in the custom control, the method *ssjsCode* will be invoked.

Comment: I am confused about the <xc:ccMethod> block.  Where does it go?   On my CC or on my XP?

Comment: Also looks like that works for CSJS.  Is there a wy to do it with SSJS?

Comment: The <xc:ccMethod> block is on your XPage. ccMethod is the custom control in this example. It works with SSJS & CSJS.

Comment: Sorry for being so dense, I'm such a newb.  But are there 2 CCs?  ccMethod and cCSJS?   Do you have a working example?   Also how can I pass an object to my custom function?  I know I could do this with other CC properties but I'd rather pass the values back to my programmer via an object

Comment: Added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks doe the update.  How would I use the value supplied by the CC button to set a value an edit box on my xPage?  I tried app.createMethodBinding("#{javascript: getComponent('inputText1').setValue(args[0]); }", null);   but I am getting an error.  How does the event handler on the xPage know about the args array set by the CC?  I don't see where it is being passed.

Comment: This is the error I am getting

Error calling method 'invoke(com.ibm.xsp.domino.context.DominoFacesContext, null)' on java class 'com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding'
Error while executing JavaScript action expression

Comment: 1. All variables/functions/whatever in SSJS are reachable everywhere as soon as they are defined.

Comment: 2. But what is my error?  If I place that same code within a button, it works just fine.

Comment: 1. So for my documentation to my end user programmers, I need to let them know about args?

Comment: Hi @SvenHasselbach, I'm a little late to the game, but.. I have everything working, however, when I view the custom property on my CC that holds the SSJS, it is blank, however, if I look at the source code, it is there as <xc:this.onClickCode>. Any idea why? It's set as a type of javax.faces.el.MethodBinding and editor method binding editor. Any idea's why?

Answer (score 1):

Define an arbitrary event handler anywhere on the page containing the custom control, and be sure to give it an id:

```
<xp:eventHandler id="customEvent" event="customEvent">
<xp:this.action>
<![CDATA[#{javascript://your custom code}]]>
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

You can then pass the method binding associated with that event handler into a custom property of the custom control that accepts a MethodBinding (or "object"):

```
getComponent("customEvent").getAction();
```

Then, from inside your custom control, you can call the method binding directly:

```
var customMethod = compositeData.get("customEvent");
var customArguments = compositeData.get("customEventArguments");
customMethod.invoke(facesContext, customArguments);
```

Make sure that the "customEventArguments" property for your custom control is set to allow multiple... this forces the property to be treated as an array, which the invoke method expects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fourth option. Don't include the button on your Custom Control. Instead, add an Editable Area, with `id="actionButton"`. You can tell the developer they need to add a button and where by using something like this in the Design Definition of the Custom Control:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" style="background-color:#4a4a4a;color:#fff;">
Add a button to the facet below.<br/>
<xp:callback facetName="actionButton" id="callback1"></xp:callback>
</xp:view>
```

The inclusion of xp:callback on the Design Definition will give a drop area at runtime for the developer to add the button. (The button may need to be in a Panel or other Container Control, I'm not sure). If you already have other Editable Areas on your Customer Control, youo'll need to include those in the Design Definition as well.